# Data Analysis in Splunk

Tags: splunk

How do you perform data analysis for Splunk?
I'm told there are no traditional DBs in Splunk - do you install non-relational DBs like mongoDB and configure it to connect to your Splunk instances/environments?

Comment: Could you please explain what is meant by "data analysis for Splunk" because I don't understand why one would perform data analysis on a data analysis tool.  You are correct in that Splunk does not use a traditional database - it stores data in a proprietary format.  It is possible to connect Splunk to a relational database to read data, though.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to connect traditional databases to Splunk, use [DB Connect](https://splunkbase.splunk.com/app/2686)

It supports

> DB2/Linux, Informix, MemSQL, MySQL, AWS Aurora, Microsoft SQL Server, Oracle, PostgreSQL, AWS RedShift, SAP SQL Anywhere, Sybase ASE, Sybase IQ, and Teradata

Splunk *is* a data analysis tool

What use case(s) are you trying to solve that you think it should be/have a database?